# Hide specific domain model fields in TYPO3 new/edit wizards

Tags: typo3, settings, domain-model

As the title says, I would like to hide specific fields of a domain model in TYPO3 new and edit wizards. These fields are read-only and are being filled by my own actions during the related actions.
Is this possible via TCA settings or similar ?!
Thanks in advance, Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use TCA type [**passthrough**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/6.2/Reference/Columns/Passthrough/Index.html) to hide a field completely.

From the docs: *"Can be saved/updated through TCE but the value is not evaluated in any way and the field has no rendering in the TCEforms."*

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['nav_title']['config']['type'] = 'passthrough';
```

2) Or Use **[TCEFORM disabled](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html#tceform-confobj)** to hide the field in the edit forms, see [here](https://somethingphp.com/typo3-backend-experience/)

```
TCEFORM.pages.nav_title.disabled = 1
```

Comment: this doesn`t help me much, I know about this setting. But I want those fields to be shown. Since they are readyOnly though, they shall be hidden ONLY in new/edit wizard.

Comment: I updated my answer: Do I understand you correctly, you want the value of your specific fields displayed e.g. in the list view but you don't want them displayed in the edit forms and they should never be editable whatsoever?

Comment: yes exactly. the optimum would be, to hide those fields for new/edit, but show those values in list/show.
Just to make things more clear : those records represent objects coming from an xml-webservice-interface. Some data may be specified (userdata) and other data is meta-data generated by the interface.
Inlcuded in that meta - data is e.g. the main id in the foreign system of that specific order as well as modification-datetimes / -user, linked records etc.
I think the TCEFORM disabled will help me.. I will look into that now !

Comment: ok, good luck. The various configuration options of TYPO3 **can** be confusing so I'm interested too if you come up with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Mark field as readOnly in TCA: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#readonly